# Insert into table not working and no error through php page

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to insert into a table. My issue with INSERT INTO categories is that its never inserting data into the table and there is no error. I am using almost the same query in code with a different table and there it's working. Any clue?

```
<?php 
$action = $_GET['action'] ; 
if ($action=='question')
  question();
elseif ($action=='categories')
  categories();

function question() {
  if ((isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) &&  $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true))
  {
    $include("db.php");
    $category = $_POST['category'] ; 
    $subcategory = $_POST['subCategory'] ; 
    $question = $_POST['question'] ; 
    $answer = $_POST['answer'] ; 

    $query = "INSERT INTO faq (category,subcategory,question,answer)   
      VALUES('.$category.','.$subcategory.','.$question.','.$answer')";
    $success = mysql_query($query);

    if ($success)
    {
      echo '<a href="admin.php" >done >';       
    }
    else 
    {
      echo mysql_error();
    }

  }
}


function categories(){
  if ( ! (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && ! $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true))
  {
    include("db.php");
    $category = $_POST['category'] ; 
    $subcategory = $_POST['subCategory'] ; 

    $query = "INSERT INTO categories (category,subcategory)
      VALUES( '$category' , '$subcategory')";
    $success = mysql_query($query);

    if ($success)
    {
      echo '<a href="admin.php" >done>';
    }
    else 
    {
      echo mysql_error();
    }

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello there [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)!

Comment: You should not build SQL strings in this way. Google SQL injection and you'll learn why.

Comment: am aware of SQLi ill handle it once issue fixed

Comment: What does "there is no error" mean exactly? Do you get to one of the "done" link? ? Do you get to one of the `echo mysql_error();` line? Which insert doesn't work? What is your query string on your url (everything from the "?" on) when this doesn't work?

Comment: insert into categories works fine , with done echo insert into faq nothing happened white page no echo no error nothing at all

Comment: If you are using different code than what is included in your question, could you append the current code so that we have a better idea of what you're working with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues:

- If you are combining variables into a string, you can use the "." character to join them, or you can include variables within the string, so long as the string is wrapped in double quotation marks. In your code, you were doing both at once.
- You were not santising your database input.
- Your logic checks for the "categories" function were incorrect.
- Your hyperlink tags were missing the closing tags.

See the amended code below.

```
<?php 

$action = $_GET['action'];

if( $action=='question' )
  question();
elseif( $action=='categories' )
  categories();

function question(){
  if( isset( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) &&  $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true ){

    include( 'db.php' );

    $category = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['category'] ); 
    $subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['subCategory'] ); 
    $question = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['question'] );
    $answer = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['answer'] );

    $query = "INSERT INTO faq ( category , subcategory , question , answer ) VALUES( '{$category}' , '{$subcategory}' , '{$question}' , '{$answer}' )";

    echo "SQL Query to execute: $query"; # Debug Message

    $success = mysql_query( $query );

    if ( $success ){
      echo '<a href="admin.php">done</a>'; 
    }else{
      echo mysql_error();
    }

  }
}


function categories(){
  if( !( isset( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) || $_SESSION['loggedin']==true ) ){

    include( 'db.php' );
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['category'] ); 
    $subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['subCategory'] );

    $query = "INSERT INTO categories ( category , subcategory ) VALUES ( '{$category}' , '{$subcategory}' )";

    echo "SQL Query to execute: $query"; # Debug Message

    $success = mysql_query( $query );

    if( $success ){
      echo '<a href="admin.php">done</a>';
    }else{
      echo mysql_error();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan: Try the amended code above. It should echo the SQL code to be executed, prefixed by "SQL Query to execute:". Login to the database through phpMyAdmin or similar and attempt to run the SQL Query directly. The code is good - it has to be a problem with something outside of the above amended code. Whether it is something in the **db.php** file, or the fields you are editing, or something like that.

Comment: how come error in db.php and am using the same to insert into categories  if you notice , there is 2 function one  to faq and other to categories , categories insert works fine with echo done msg and data already in DB , meanwhile categories show no error no insert , just white page

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan: I am saying the code I have provided, and the code provided by JamWaffles looks correct. So rather than trying to find a bug in half the picture (when it doesn't appear likely that it is there), I am suggesting that you may want to look at the other half of the picture, being the dependencies this code relies on. Do the debugging as mentioned above first, then we'll argue the merits of this advice.

Comment: yes i did , inserting into  categories which use function categories works  100% and show debug msg also  , inserting into faq which use function question  not working no result just blank page

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan: So, with a yes/no answer - Have you: 1) used the above code, 2) seen SQL statements shown in the browser, 3) executed those statements within phpMyAdmin or similar? In addition to that, were the statements, when executed within phpMyAdmin, successful, or did you see errors?

Answer (score 4):

First off, to help debugging, I'd put these two lines at the top of your scripts to show all the errors produced. Don't put these in a production environment, however.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Change

```
$query = "INSERT INTO faq (category,subcategory,question,answer) VALUES('.$category.','.$subcategory.','.$question.','.$answer')";
```

To this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO faq (category,subcategory,question,answer) VALUES('".$category."','".$subcategory."','".$question."','".$answer."')";
```

You have missed out a `.` (dot) after `$answer`; it was a syntax error, not a query error.

To make things a bit simpler, you can actually omit the dots completely:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO faq (category,subcategory,question,answer) VALUES('$category','$subcategory','$question','$answer')";
```

**Do be aware of SQL injection attacks; use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to make your query safe(er)**

---

Another issue might be your include file. Try changing

```
include("db.php");
```

To

```
require("db.php");
```

This will fail if the include file can't be found. In this case, go fix!

Comment: thanks for ur time , but nothing or syntax fix this issue even no error reported

Comment: @Marco Try doing a `print_r($_POST)` before the `$query = ""` line. This will print the `$_POST` array and show if there's anything in it or not.

Comment: also no output just blank page

Comment: It's possible that the input is breaking the statement. Try this
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
Then continue with echo '<a href="admin.php" >done>';

Comment: Still have a bug in your suggested code. It'll produce `...VALUES('.TheCategory.','.TheSubcategory.','.TheQuestion.','.TheAnswer.')`

Comment: @Lucanos: Thanks very much. How could I have missed that! Edited.

Comment: @Marco Do you at least get an `Array ()` (blank array)?

Comment: @JamWafles: Hate to be pedantic, but your 1st suggested revision (with the variables included within the string) is now missing quotation marks/apostrophes around the (assumed) string values. `... ) VALUES(".$category."," ...` should be `... ) VALUES('".$category."','" ...` OR `... ) VALUES(\"".$category."\",\"" ...`

Comment: @Lucanos That's not pedantic at all. Thanks for pointing out my mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, used `or die(mysql_error());` and realized I wasn't doing `addslashes($string)` on one of my variables. It had characters I needed to escape.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mysterious situation. And worse, on a remote, identical, database the same code was working. The solution was to define a default value (any value) to all the database fields... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i have been stuck in this problem for a long time the only solution i found is

use mysqli instead of mysql because in newer versions of php these mysql has been deprecated for example

use the following methods

and make sure keep the order correct dirst the variable e.g '$conn' and then database name in the method 'mysqli_select_db($conne,'checksum');'.

similarly in 'mysqli_query($conne,$enter_command);' first variable and then the variable for query.

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
mysqli_select_db($conne,'checksum'); // checksum is database name
mysqli_query($conne,$enter_command);
mysqli_close($conne);
```

also make sure to give spaces when entering database table columns

```
$enter_command = "INSERT INTO dbase (name , lastname , password) VALUES ('".$name."','".$lastname."','".$password."')";
```

you can also use this syntax

```
$enter_command = "INSERT INTO dbase (name , lastname , password) VALUES ('{$name}','{$lastname}','{$password}')";
```

try avoiding sql injection

```
$gender      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
```

hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working just fine, The issue here is the database auto increment was not set. This can happen When auto increment is not set. you will not be able to insert additional records beyond one no matter how many times you run your script.  If you are having this kind of issue, check to make sure auto increment is enabled.

This is not really an error but the developer of mysql or php should give a warning when the user forgets to enable auto increment so the user has the option to fix it or ignore it.